# Java: Infix to Post Fix Conversion

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to input an infix expression and convert it to a postfix expression using Stack class. I will be outputting the postfix expression as a String.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Fix 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter expression in infix: ");
        String input= s.nextLine();

        Stack<String> operator= new Stack<String>();
        Stack<String> operand= new Stack<String>();
        System.out.println("Created stacks...");
        String expression="";
        transferToString(input, operator, operand, expression);
        System.out.println("Created string... ");
        System.out.println(expression);

    }
}
```

Here is the statement that creates the String *expression* in the void transferToString method:

```
else if (operand.empty()==false)
            {
                String str1 = input.substring(i++,i+2);
                expression.concat(operand.pop());
                expression.concat(str1);
            }
```

The above code is a nested if statement, with the primary condition being whether the next character is an operand or not.

In the above else-if statement, I pop an operand from the stack *operand*, and concatenate it to String *expression*. In the main method, I print out expression.

However, this is my output:

```
Enter expression in infix: 
(1+5)
Created stacks...
Pushed first operator!
Created string...
```

For some reason, the String is not getting printed - I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `transferToString` method does not return anything. Return the `expression` variable.

```
Stack<String> operator= new Stack<String>();
Stack<String> operand= new Stack<String>();
String expression="";
```

Also note that the declarations above is not needed in the `main` method, you can put it in the `transferToString` method. Thus your `transferToString` method will just accept the parameter `input`.

This will be the new look of your `main` method and `transferToString` method.

`main` Method :

```
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter expression in infix: ");
        String input= s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Created stacks...");
        String expression = transferToString(input);
        System.out.println("Created string... ");
        System.out.println(expression);

    }
```

`transferToString` method:

```
public static String transferToString(String input){
    Stack<String> operator= new Stack<String>();
    Stack<String> operand= new Stack<String>();
    String expression="";

    // Copy the code of your old transferToString method here

    return expression;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `expression` that has scope within `main()` is never being set to the `expression` that is being set within `transferToString`.

Simply set the `expression` that is defined within main to `transferToString`, and have `transferToString` return the newly created `expression`.

Like so: `String expression = transferToString(input, operator, operand, "");`

Always read through your code line by line and consider what each line is actually doing, it will solve lots of silly errors!